# The JSON data in request body is not getting parsed using body-parser

Tags: node.js, json, express, body-parser

When I send a POST request using postman to localhost:8080/api/newUser with request body:

```
{name: "Harry Potter"}
```

At server end console.log(req.body) prints:

```
{ '{name: "Harry Potter"}': '' }
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next();
});

router
    .route('/newUser')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
    });

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(8080);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are the parameter you setting in postman

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In express.js the order in which you declare middleware is very important. `bodyParser` middleware must be defined early than your own middleware (api endpoints).

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies

router
    .route('/newUser')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
    });

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Done @NikhilWanpal

Comment: For me the solution was setting proper header `Content-Type: application/json` for curl

Comment: @michalzuber's solution worked for me as well. Both .json() and .urlencoded() look at the headers of a request and based on the `Content-Type` the right middleware is used. I am using jQuery's ajax and it sets the `ContentType` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. That caused the server to not use the json middleware.

Comment: I am having this issue. Because of CORS/web `fetch` limitations I need to set `ContentType` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and am receiving `{ '{name: "Harry Potter"}': '' }`. Is there a way to fix this or do I just need to `JSON.parse` the key?

Answer (score 10):

## **Change the request header**

```
'Content-Type':'application/json'
```

So that bodyParser can parse the body.

*That is what works for me. i am using angular 2+ with express(body-parser)

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out how to pass objects from Axios as key-value pairs and eventually decided to go with an alternative because setting the Content-Type: "application/json" retuned an empty object.

If the above options don't work for you, I would consider:

- Extracting the key (which should contain the entire
  object)
- Parsing the key
- Accessing the values of the newly created objects

This worked for me:

var obj = (Object.keys(req.body)[0])

var NewObj = JSON.parse(obj)

var name = apiWords["Key1"]

var image = apiWords["Key2"]