# Express Body-Parser does not parse data correctly

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, curl

I am stuck using `Node.js/express`, `body-parser` and `curl`:

My `curl POST` request looks as such:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: Application/json" -d '{"www":"ssss"}' localhost:3000/login
```

It hits the following endpoint:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    let validatedJson = JsonValidator.validateJson(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Yet the `console.log` outputs this: `{ www: 'ssss' }` and not this `{"www":"ssss"}`

removing the header outputs this: `{ '{"www":"ssss"}': '' }`

What is happening? "could be happening" and how do I get the proper output?

Comment: JSON gets parsed to a Javascript object that doesn't have the double quotes when console.logged. It's not an error.

Comment: Thanks! yet how do you handle invalid or incomplete JSON if it is being cast as soon as req.body is called on the server side? How to validate it before an error occurs?

Comment: If it's not valid JSON, the body parser should throw an error. In order to react properly, you should implement some [error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

Comment: If the JSON is malformed you should get a Syntax error.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I just come from Java and Node takes some getting used to :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388507/the-json-data-in-request-body-is-not-getting-parsed-using-body-parser